# Why isn't awk working as expected

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I am trying to tab-separate a colon-separated file. It works as far as I don't add a heading to it.

This works:

```
[root@cloudops11l ~]# awk 'BEGIN {FS=":";OFS="\t"} {print $1,$3,$4}' /etc/passwd | head -3
root    0       0
bin     1       1
daemon  2       2
```

This just messes away the first record in output:

```
[root@cloudops11l ~]# awk 'BEGIN {print "Username\tUID\tGID"} {FS=":";OFS="\t"} {print $1,$3,$4}' /etc/passwd | head -3
Username        UID     GID
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin     1       1
```

Answer (score 3):

You are no longer setting `FS` and `OFS` in the `BEGIN` block, so the setting only takes effect after processing the first input line.  Move it back into the `BEGIN` block.

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Username\tUID\tGID"; FS=":";OFS="\t"}
    {print $1,$3,$4}' /etc/passwd | head -n 3
```